# Light/Dark system setting on Linux

Tags: support, dark-mode

[Since March 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/), Stack Overflow offers a theme selection. It can be set to *Light*, *Dark*, and *System setting*.

[image]

When using *System setting*, what variable does the site read and how do I adjust it? (I'm on Linux if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Linux alone doesn't make enough of a difference - different Linux *distros* may do things differently (some may have, others don't).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they read the [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) CSS property with the value `dark` or `light`.